# NSManagedObject added to relationship twice

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an NSManagedObject A, which has a to many relationship with object B.
If I create object B, and add it to relationship for A TWICE for example

```
B = get somehow
[A addObjectB:B];
[A addObjectB:B];
```

Will the graph be still be consistent or do I have to make sure that I do not duplicate relationship in some way? I know it's a set that manages relationship so duplicates should not be allowed, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: I don't like trial and error in an app that must work :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "to-many" relationship is represented by a NSSet and is unique.

If you add an object to a relationship set multiple times it will only appear in the relationship once.